# scalajs-bundler: which compiled file should be included in HTML?

Tags: npm, scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I'm trying to handle my JS dependencies with scalajs-bundler for my Scala.js project. It successfully downloads my dependency (d3.js), but I don't know how to include my code and the dependency in my HTML file.

I tried every files I found on `target/scala-2.12/` but it didn't work.

- with `target/scala-2.12/*-jsdeps.js` it doesn't run my main method.
- with `target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/*-fastopt.js` I get `ReferenceError: exports is not defined` in Firefox.

I don't want to use a facade, this is a short-term project and I plan to use `js.Dynamic`.

A side question: can I still use source maps with scalajs-bundler ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that the final bundle file `*-fastopt-bundle.js` (the one to include) was missing, and apparently it was because webpack was silently unable to run because npm packages are referring to `node` (and not `nodejs`) in their shebang.

So the solution was to install `nodejs-legacy` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include both the `*-jsdeps.js` and the `*-fastopt.js`.

`*-jsdeps.js` contains your dependencies, `*-fastopt.js` contains the Scala.js code (and the invocation of the `main` method if you enable `scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer`).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but apparently the problem was elsewhere (see my answer).